# RegEx: How to modify the content of a group

Tags: php, regex

I have a source code from a website that includes several image tags. I want to use the content of the alt attribute as my src. So I want to change this

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/img/img.png" alt="A Title">
```

to this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.org/img/a_title.png" alt="A Title">
```

To use the alt attribute value in the src attribute, I use the following regex

```
/(<img.+?src=").+?(".+?alt="(.+?)">)/
```

And use `$1$3$2` for subtitution.

I use PHP as language.

But how can I modify the third group (to lower case, replace spaces with underscore)?

Comment: What language are you using? Please note that regexes and HTML are not good friends.

Comment: PHP. I used regex for other HTML manipulations, it worked for my cases.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` and inside the anonymous function, access the third group and make it lowercase and perform other changes. But you should really have a look at the HTML parser (PHP `DOMDocument` with `DOMXPath` are really cool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working implementation using preg_match:

```
$input = "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/img/img.png\" alt=\"A Title\">";

$re = '~(<img\s*src=".*\/).*(\.[^"]*)("\s*alt="([^"]+).*)~';

preg_match($re, $input, $m);

$filtered_string = $m[1] . str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($m[4])) . $m[2] . $m[3];
```

Output:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/img/a_title.png" alt="A Title">
```

Online implementation [here](http://ideone.com/LNiAlS).

**UPDATE**: preg_replace_callback implementation:

```
$filtered_string = preg_replace_callback(
    '~(<img.*src=".*\/).*(\.[^"]*)(".*alt="([^"]+).*)~',
    function($m) {
      return $m[1] . str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($m[4])) . $m[2] . $m[3];
    },
    $str
);
```

Online implementation of the second version [here](http://ideone.com/CcyRbg).

Comment: @DaFunkyAlex: no problem but i think the hjpotter92 implementation does not work as you expected...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PHP, use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$newLine = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<img.+?src=").+?(".+?alt="(.+?)">)/',
    function($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . strtolower( str_replace(' ', '_', $matches[3]) ) . $matches[2];
    },
    $str
);
```